# cakephp: Order index by ID desc after ADD

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

In my application, all index views are sorted by name ASC, by default.
I need to order data by ID desc, only after adding a new row, to help the user see the last added row in top of the index.

in controller, add function:

```
if ($this->Assets->save($asset)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The asset has been saved.'));
            //die('new id:' . $asset->id);
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
```

This try did not work:

```
return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index', 'order' => ['id' => 'DESC']]);
```

what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have pagination enabled for your views?

if so the correct link should be

```
return $this->redirect([
    'action' => 'index', 
    '?' => [
        'sort' => 'id',
        'direction' => 'desc'
    ]
]);
```